# Some questions about the proof of backwards mathematical induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, peano-axioms

The backwards mathematical induction is Let $n$ be an natural number and $P(m)$ be a property, and if $P(m+1)$ is true, then $P(m)$ is true. The problem is given that $P(n)$ is true, prove $\forall m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\leq n$, $P(m)$ is true.

What make me puzzled is the hint in the book as I should make induction according to $n$, but I think that the $n$ is fixed? What’s the meaning of changing $n$?

You could find the problem on tao’s analysis.

Comment: The claim implicitly includes that it should be true for *any* fixed $n$, that is, you need to prove it for *all* $n\in\Bbb N$, so induction on $n$ seems adequate.

Comment: But the question is $\forall m, P(m)$ isn’t it right to prove the correctness of $P(m)$

Comment: You're not being asked to prove the $P(m)$. You are being asked to prove a statement $S(n)$ which says "If $P(n)$ is true then so is $P(m)$ for all $m\le n$". You can prove statement $S(n)$ is true for every $n$ by induction.

Comment: ahhhh. I know it.